# Why has everything only one colour in my final render?

Tags: rendering, materials, render-layers

i am new to blender and this amazing 3D community .I was working on a fun project but the fun project become a headed I don't know how .I got wrecking ball , cubes and a base but problem is everything showing same colour in final render .in render mode everything is fine even in camera also but I don't know whey final render is showing only one colour.here are some images of my fun project(which turn into headed .)
[image]

this one was rendered mode.this is what I want .

[image: this is what I am getting]

this is what I am getting blender is not even reading emission .

P.S -  this was just a fun project so i did not took much care of textures and lighting as I planned to keep it myself.
hope I gave enough details .

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE. Could you show your Render Layers tab instead of the Scene tab? What happens if you enable Render layer options in the 3D viewport?

Comment: Attach your file here http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/?ref=be-community-add-2

Comment: @Carlo  thanks i just checked my render layer tab and found something strange .There was a material assign to render tab which was creating all trouble .I removed it and boom! it got fixed .

Comment: Please put the answer into an actual answer, instead of rewriting the question title.